# Drop Down value not updating to the selected option

Tags: flutter, dart

I have gone through other similar questions but none of them work for me.

When I select the value in the Dropdown, setState method is called and the new value is stored in dropdownValue variable. But the change is not reflected on the screen.

```
class _ComparisonScreenState extends State<ComparisonScreen> {
  Widget titleWidget = const Text('Loading...'); //Initial widget which gets replaced by a drowpdown menu after async call to the DB returns values. 
  String dropdownValue = 'Contradiction 1'; //holds the initial value in the dropdown.

  @override
  void initState() {
    databaseObject.getContradictions().then( //async call to the DB to fetch data.
      (contradictions) { //stores the list of contradictions
        setState(
          () {
            titleWidget = DropdownButton<String>(
              isExpanded: true,
              // isDense: true,
              items: contradictions.header.map((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(value),
                    subtitle: (Text(value)),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
              value: dropdownValue,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              iconSize: 24,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              underline: Container(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.white70,
              ),
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    dropdownValue = newValue!;
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const CommonDrawer(currentScreen: 'ComparisonScreen'),
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: const [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
            child: Icon(Icons.settings),
          ),
        ],
        title: titleWidget,
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

thank you

Comment: i think you need to rearrange your code.  store your contradictions in a variable and move your titleWidget creation under widget build method. access the contradictions variable to populate your dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setState()` the framework schedules a new build call and widget sub-tree get recreated. Then the framework compares new widget sub-tree with the previous widget sub-tree to see if there is any changes. As your `titleWidget` object doesn't get recreated after selecting value from the dropdown, the `dropdownValue` doesn't get changed in the `titleWidget`. Simply this means you have to create new instances of widget objects to reflect their changes during the build call. There is a widget provided by the framework called `FutureBuilder` that you can use to build widgets asynchronously.

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: databaseObject.getContradictions,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final contradictions = snapshot.data;
            return your_title_widget_here;
        }
        return your_loading_widget_here;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What i did, I use a method and pass the value

```
void changedData(String? value){
  dropdownValue = value!;
}
```

then in onChanged

```
onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    changedData(newValue!)
                  },
                );
              },
```

I am not sure but you can try like this.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. One of the other answers did though.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because your DropdownButton is in `initState()`. If I'm not wrong, SetState will rebuild `build` instead of `initState()` so, try to place your DropdownButton in `build`, and initialize your item for DropdownButton in `initState()`.